# php mkdir permisson problems in apche user environment

Tags: php, mkdir

I have an "www user environment" on an apache 
- meaning I can access my personal website via http://Servername/~username" -

When I try to create an directory via php script

```
// create test directory if not exist
if (!is_dir('./test')) {
    mkdir('./test', 0755, true);
    }
```

I get an error (warning)

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mkdir(): Permission denied in <b>/home/rob/www/IPMS/modules/GenerateFile.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
```

this is clear because the directory belongs to username (rob) and not www-data

so I know why but I do not know how to solve the problem

Comment: Why don't you simply assign the group ownership to the user group the http server works under and grant group writing permission to the folder that http server is meant to be able to write files and folder to?

Comment: you mean like "usermod -a -G rob www-data" - but this is still not working - how do i grant group writing permission to the group "rob" where I added the user "www-data"

Comment: `chgrp -R www-data some-folder`, then `chmod -R g+w some-folder`, assuming that the correct user group name is `www-data` (depends on your distribution and setup)